# Runtime Error while using the class:SellarMDAPromoteConnect, as given in the OpenMDAO tutorial

Tags: openmdao

I am just getting started with the tutorials of OpenMDAO, I was trying out the *Sellar - A Two-Discipline Problem with a Nonlinear Solver* tutorial and soon ran into an error. There are three ways included in the website to promote and connect input-output variables, the third method titled "Variable Promotion and Connect Statements" has the class named *SellarMDAPromoteConnect*. When I try to run the optimization setup, the code throws a runtime error

> <*model*> <*class SellarMDAPromoteConnect*>: Output not found for response 'obj'

I ran the following in the console:

```
!openmdao check -c all <_file name_>.py
```

which shows the first error:

> File "D:\softwares\anaconda\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\openmdao\core\system.py", line 3250, in get_responses
> key = in_abs = prom2abs_in[name][0]
>
> KeyError: 'obj'

Can anyone kindly explain why this error pops up and how to fix it while using the same class SellarMDAPromoteConnect? I cannot come up with any convincing reason(s) to explain this error. Every line of the code I used is same as given in the website (link attached [**here**](https://openmdao.org/newdocs/versions/latest/basic_user_guide/multidisciplinary_optimization/linking_vars.html)), I have attached a screenshot of the code snippet used to run the optimization problem setup, just in case you want to have a look at it

Optimization setup code snippet

[image: Optimization setup code snippet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your run script has a namespace detail incorrect. The example you pulled from used a mixture of promotion and connection to be illustrative. The `obj` variable is computed and owned by the `obj_cmp` ExecComp. Only two of the inputs (`x` and `z`) were promoted. The other two inputs (`y1` and `y2`) were not and neither was the output objective (`obj`).

To add the objective you would do the following:

```
# prob.model.add_objective('obj') # wrong scope
prob.model.add_objective('obj_cmp.obj') # correct scope
```

There are a few ways to easily determine the correct names for variables:

1. Use the `list_outputs` method on a group that owns the variables in question.

`prob.model.list_outputs(prom_name=True)`

gives:

```
varname   val   prom_name
--------  ----  -------------
cycle
  d1
    y1    [1.]  d1.y1
  d2
    y2    [1.]  d2.y2
obj_cmp
  obj     [1.]  obj_cmp.obj
con_cmp1
  con1    [1.]  con_cmp1.con1
con_cmp2
  con2    [1.]  con_cmp2.con2
```

If you prefer a more visual layout, the N2 also has the information you want:

[image: N2 diagram of Sellar Example Problem]

Comment: Thanks a ton, Justin! I finally got a hold of how promote and connect work. I need one final clarification regarding the command you used, which is "prob.model.list_variables(prom_name=True)". Unfortunately, this gave me an error, so checked the documentation page which suggested the alternative "prob.model.list_inputs(val=False, prom_name=True)" to use and it ran without any errors. So does the command you used belong to the previous version of openmdao? Or perhaps may be I missed a few things in my openmdao installation? Thanks again!

Comment: Just to elaborate the error was " AttributeError: 'SellarMDAPromoteConnect' object has no attribute 'list_variables' "

Comment: sorry about that. "list outputs". Answer was edited to correct